# mostrar en el Template los datos segun el valor del select

Tags: python, django

necesito ayuda coleg@s ya que soy novato en Django!

Debo mostrar la información que tengo guardada en una tabla según la opción elegida de un select. Al seleccionar la opción del select en el `template` guardo el valor en una variable utilizando JavaScript (hasta aqui todo bien). En la `views` especificamente en el metodo `post` de la clase obtengo el valor (`request.POST['fecha']`) y al verificar con un `print` todos los datos estan correctos

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
            if action == 'search_fecha':
                data=[]
                CE = ConsumoElect.objects.all()
                CE = CE.filter(fecha = request.POST['fecha'])
                for i in CE:
                    data.append([
                        i.id,
                        i.pgd.name,
                        i.fecha.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                        i.lec_madrugada,
                    ])
                    print(data)
            else:
                data['error'] = 'Ha ocurrido un error'
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

El promeblema es que no se como mostrar esos datos en mi `Template`. Les pido que me ayuden con esto.

Muestro el código de mi template

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="data">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Nro</th>
                <th scope="col">Tipo PGD</th>
                <th scope="col">Fecha de registro</th>
                <th scope="col">Lectura Madrugada</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ #mostrar datos aqui }}</td>
                <td>{{ #mostrar datos aqui }}</td>
                <td>{{ #mostrar datos aqui }}</td>
                <td>{{ #mostrar datos aqui }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

se me ocurre que podrías solucionarlo con una solicitud AJAX al servidor.

prueba a desarrollar una función en Js que se ejecute cuando se cambia la selección en el elemento select agregando un manejador de eventos:

```
document.getElementById("fecha").addEventListener("change", searchByFecha);
```

de todos modos, yo lo plantearía de manera más sofisticada: create una aplicación en Js con algún framework (Vue o React) y utiliza Django exclusivamente como API con (por ejemplo) djangorestframework. Eso de meter por todas partes llamadas ajax en vanillaJs es bastante engorroso.

**Actualización:**

Si como dices ya tienes tu petición ajax, simplemente podrías actualizar la tabla con js, con algo parecido a esto:

```
function updateTable(data) {
    const tableBody = document.querySelector("#data tbody");
    tableBody.innerHTML = '';
    data.forEach(item => {
        const row = document.createElement("tr");

        row.innerHTML = `
            <td>${item[0]}</td>
            <td>${item[1]}</td>
            <td>${item[2]}</td>
            <td>${item[3]}</td>
        `;
        tableBody.appendChild(row);
    });
}
```

Comment: buenas amigo! Realmente ya tengo un codigo AJAX para obtener el valor de la fecha que tiene el select y ese valor lo tengo aca en la variable `CE`, eso funciona perfectamente, mi problema es mostrar los datos filtrados en el `template`. Y no utilizo Djangorestframework

Comment: si ya tienes tu ajax realizando la petición, puedes actualizar la tabla en tu template utilizando JavaScript para mostrar los datos filtrados. Create una función updateTable(data) donde data sean los datos filtrados. Creas la tabla con js y haces un tableBody.appendChild(row); por cada dato.